# Continuity of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$ on $(0,\infty)$, show $f$ is continuous.

If I can show that $\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+n^2x}\}$ converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, then it follows that $f$ is continuous $(0,\infty)$ since each function is continuous on that interval. I'm trying to use the M-test, but I can't find the right bound: If $x\geq 1$, then $\frac{1}{1+n^2x}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$. But I can't find a bound that works for all of $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea, using uniform convergence. Instead, try this: fix any $x_0\in(0,\infty),$ then fix $c\in(0,\infty)$ with $c<x_0.$ Can you show that the series converges uniformly on $[c,\infty)$? Do you see how that helps you?

Answer (score 4):

You won't find a good bound for all of $(0, \infty)$; after all, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$$

What you *can* do is apply the $M$-test with the obvious bound on $[1, \infty)$, which gives continuity on $[1, \infty)$.

Then apply the $M$-test with the obvious bound on $[1/2, \infty)$, which gives continuity on $[1/2, \infty)$.

Rinse and repeat as needed.