# Confusion about Uniform Convergence of Series

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

My confusion stems from the following two examples:

Example 1: Consider the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$. Does this converge uniformly on $[0,a)$ for each $0<a<1$. Answer: Yes. Does this converge uniformly on $[0,1)$? Answer: No

Example 2: Consider the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$. Does this series converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$? Answer: Yes, because for each $a>0$, the series converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$.

My confusion is that the first example seems to contradict the reasoning in the second example: That is, to show uniform convergence on an interval, it is sufficient to show uniform convergence on appropriate sub-intervals. Can someone please explain?

Comment: The second series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, since its terms do not converge uniformly to $0$ on that interval. Regardless, one can't infer uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$ if one has uniform convergence on $(a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra That's what I thought, but it was a question on a practice analysis qualifying exam. I actually asked about it on mathstack a couple of days ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850010/continuity-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac11n2x

Comment: In your linked question, you are suggested to show uniform convergence on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$, not because it could imply uniform converge on $(0,\infty)$ (it doesn't), but rather to show continuity of $f$ on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$, which *does* imply continuity on $(0,\infty)$.